# put html attribute from php response via ajax

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

Im trying to do a call ajax (it´s works) to retrieve an array with the checkboxes prev checked ,but doesn´t work ,I think the problem could be find in jQuery.inArray why the rest works

```
<input type="checkbox" class="controla" name="control[]"  value="0">
<input type="checkbox" class="controla" name="control[]"  value="1">
<input type="checkbox" class="controla" name="control[]"  value="2">
....
```

The Jquery show like this

```
(function( $ ){
   $.fn.cargaTabla = function() {
        $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
                    url: "AccionesPrueba.php?accion=controles",
                    data: {fecha : '25'},
                    success: function(response) {
                        var controles = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
                        $('.controla').each(function(){
                            if (jQuery.inArray(jQuery(this).val(), controles) != -1){
                                this.attr('checked', 'checked');
                            }
                        });
                    }
            });
        };
    })( jQuery );

        $().cargaTabla();
```

`AccionesPrueba.php`

```
if($_GET["accion"] == "controles"){

    $fecha = $_POST['fecha'];

    $sql = "SELECT Control FROM registros WHERE Fecha = $fecha";
    $resultado = $db->consulta($sql); //call class for DB access
    if (mysqli_num_rows($resultado) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
            $datos = $row['Control'];
            $extraeDatos = explode(",", $datos);
            echo json_encode ($extraeDatos);
       }
    }
}
```

row Control from registros table show for example `1,2,7`

Comment: Where are you closing your `while` loop?

Comment: @jeroen I forgot put that here,in my code not(now I´ve edited my mistake)

Comment: This will not work if your database query returns more than 1 row. In that case you should build an array and after the loop send it once using `json_encode()`.

Comment: I only expect one row,is one row per day .Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You set your type to POST .So must call by $_POST and should change your para to like this `data: {accion:'controles',fecha : '25'}`.I think your return json data is `int` so you should change your checkbox value to `int` first ,then compare it.

```
 $('.controla').each(function(){
         var check_value = parseInt(jQuery(this).val());
         if (jQuery.inArray(check_value , controles) != -1){
                jQuery(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
           }
  });
```

Don't forget to add jQuery to your `this` code.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem

bad

```
this.attr('checked', 'checked');
```

good

```
$(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
```

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Just use .each function pre-define params .each(index, element).

```
                        $('.controla').each(function(idx, elmt){
                            if (jQuery.inArray(jQuery(elmt).val(), controles) != -1){
                                $(elmt).prop('checked', true);
                            }
                        });
```